# Limit login attempts on custom login in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I created a custom login Auth on laravel 5.4. Everything works fine. But, I want to put a login attempt which is not working on my site and contains error.

I saw the code below on other sites which is running on laravel 5.0 below but not on laravel 5.4.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;

class AuthCustomController extends Controller
{  
   use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins ;

   protected $maxLoginAttempts = 3;  
   protected $lockoutTime = 20;  

   public function loginCustom() 
   {
      //codes here
   }
}
```

Error:

`Trait 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers' not found`

Does anybody know?

Comment: What version are you using? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authenticatesandregistersusers-trait-removed-from-53 - Else just add the namespace in your use declaration.

Comment: have you included AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers using use

Comment: I am using 5.4 ., the answers on google are below 5.4 which is not working

Comment: You will not be able to use this trait anymore. You either have to implement login function via `php artisan make:auth` or to use some third party plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if that trait was removed in version 5.3:

https://laravel.com/api/5.3/search.html?search=AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers

Comment: switch to 5.2 (in the above link) and you're see it.

Comment: not a *minor* semantic release imo, more a major as you need to upgrade.

Comment: I am using 5.4. should I downgrade to 5.2? Is that what you meant?

Comment: yeah if you want that feature you may need to, though im not a Laravel expert.